# Cron job "Run Email Reminder Notification" fails - suitecrm version 7.7.4

Tags: suitecrm

When the cron job (Run Email Reminder Notification) fires in the suitecrm, I get this error in the log file, and the e-mail does not work:

```
job 96fe34f8bfbd-e804-0e15-587fe7bdcfbc(Run Email Reminder Notifications) failed in cron run
```

I'm using php_version 5.6 and suitecrm_version 7.7.4.

What is wrong?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: cron email reminder notification of suitecrm not working . gives error job 96fe34f8bfbd-e804-0e15-587fe7bdcfbc(Run Email Reminder Notifications) failed in cron run

Comment: have you tried "repair scheduler jobs"?

Comment: now it is working after running the "repair scheduler job" thank you

Answer (score 1):

Execute `Rebuild Schedulers` from the repair screen.

Make sure that you have noted all of your active scheduler jobs because after `Rebuild Schedulers` you have to create custom scheduler jobs(if there is any) manually.

Answer (score 0):

The reminder task is very brittle,
you must make sure you never delete users (I think this is what is causing it in your case)

make sure that there are no reminders due for any users that don't exist (can be checked in the database).
there may be some other instances where the task breaks, but this is a good starting point

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29874776)